# Am i doing something wrong by getting plugins from github repos?

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, paypal

I was trying to add paypal payment to my website, I'm using Gravirty form with stripe add-on but not paypal add-on.
I happened to find a github repo for the (paypal addon). so I downloaded it then uploaded it to my website and now i have the plugin.

The developer who built the site has purchesed a licence for gravity form but i don't have it as i lost connection with him otherwise i can get the addon from the original source.

Now is what I did illegal or ethically wrong?
If so, why such software and other ones are easily found and public on github?

Note: This disclaimer is found on the page "Gravity Forms PayPal Payments Standard Add-On, Git-ified. Synced manual! This repository is just a mirror of the Gravity Forms PayPal Payments Standard Add-On plugin. Please do not send pull requests and issues. http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/paypal/  "

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a development forum, not a legal or philosophy forum. These aren't questions that can (or should) be answered here. If you have legal questions, consult a lawyer. If you can't, and feel unsure, then just purchase the license legitimately.

Answer (score 0):

You did ethically wrong but that is not illegal. https://www.gravityforms.com/terms-and-conditions/

Gravity Forms is licensed under the GNU general public license (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt).

You have a lot of freedom with such tools.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but how am I ethically wrong if the licence has been purchased already by the developer and the plugin is installed legally on my site, it is just the developer didn't fullfil his promise to keep updating it.

Comment: You should not use a license that's not under your name/product.